# How to read data from redshift in aws glue job in spark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am new in aws glue and need help from community.
I have table in redshift and wanted to iterate over dataset returned by using select query in glue job in spark. I have written below code, but not able to figure out how to retrieve all the row and columns value from dataframe? Also, I am getting error...

```
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
```

Here is my sample code-

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

t = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url","myurl").option("user","myuser").option("password",mypwd).option("dbtable","(select id, years, months, days from etl.mytable where id=1) as t1").load()
print(t)
t= t.toDF()
for row in t:
  print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are calling `.toDF()` on t, which is in fact already a `DataFrame`, not a `DynamicFrame`.